# Not getting new preview builds after 10074

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I can't get Windows 10 to update to new preview build after 10074. 
I've noticed that new build was downloaded but never installed, and I can't find a way to trigger an update or download it again.